# Sum values associated with a date equal to or less than today in Google Sheets

Tags: date, google-sheets, time-series, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

So I have a table that looks like this:

| **date** | **goal** |
| --- | --- |
| 10/1/2022 | 10000 |
| 10/2/2022 | 10000 |
| 10/3/2022 | 10000 |
| 10/4/2022 | 10000 |
| 10/5/2022 | 10000 |
| 10/6/2022 | 10000 |

I would like to create a formula that Sums the goal column for the dates less than or equal to the current day. I currently have this:

```
=query(A4:B1000, "select SUM(B) WHERE A <= today()")
```

But this is throwing the following error: `Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: PARSE_ERROR: Encountered " "(" "( "" at line 1, column 31. Was expecting one of: <EOF> "group" ... "pivot" ... "order" ... "skipping" ... "limit" ... "offset" ... "label" ... "format" ... "options" ... "and"`

Any thoughts on how to proceed would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Just use `now()` instead of `today()`

Comment: Yes but you have to be very careful comparing now (a datetime) to an actual date. In my opinion use of today() is better.

Comment: @TomSharpe How so? At most it'll include today's 23:59 hours in the inclusion criteria. I think doing it inside query is still much better option.

Comment: It works in this particular case but  =query(A2:B1000, "select SUM(B) WHERE A >= now()")  doesn't select today's date for example.

Comment: @TomSharpe I see. I'll still prefer doing it inside query: `=query(A2:B1000, "select SUM(B) WHERE A >= todate(now())")`

Comment: Yes maybe that gets the best of both worlds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a typical use case for [SUMIF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093583), which will sum values in a range that meet a condition (a condition on that same range, or on a corresponding range):

```
=sumif(A4:A1000,"<="&TODAY(),B4:B1000)
```

will sum the values in `B4:B1000` for which the corresponding value in `A4:A1000` is less than or equal to today.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can still use a query if you prefer as long as you get the right syntax - see [this](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/query-dates/) for example.

```
=query(A2:B1000, "select SUM(B) WHERE A <= date '"& text(today(),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'")
```

[image]

Dates in my locale are in dd/mm/yyyy format so 6/10/2022 is tomorrow at time of writing.